# How to prove that sums of even powers is divisible by p

Tags: number-theory

For $n\leq (p-2)$
I want to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (r+k)^{n} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$
It is easy to see that it is true for odd n, since $(-a)^k \equiv -a^k$, and you can just pair up terms since there will be exactly $p$ terms all with a unique remainder.

I want to prove this for even n too, though which is what I want some help with.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: yes p is a prime

Comment: The group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic. That helps a lot here.

Comment: Newton's identities also allow a proof. It could help to think we're working in the field with p elements. To show the elementary symmetric polynomials vanish, note that the roots of $x^{p-1}-1=0$ are the $p-1$ non zero elements of the field.